# Apigee maven build tool

Tags: maven, apigee

I am using the apigee maven build tool 
https://github.com/apigee/apigee-deploy-maven-plugin

I keep running into the issue where when I run the plugin and run the sample projects it gives me an IO error when reading the config.json file , when I remove the file everything works fine . Has anybody else faced this error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.apigee.build-tools.enterprise4g:apigee-edge-maven-plugin:1.0.0:configure (configure-bundle) on project forecas
ploy-maven-plugin-master%20(3)\apigee-deploy-maven-plugin-master\samples\forecastweatherapi-simple\target\apiproxy\targets\default.xml (The syst
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal io.apigee.build-tools.enterprise4g:apigee-edge-maven-plugin:1.0.0
api: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\apigee-deploy-maven-plugin-master%20(3)\apigee-deploy-maven-plugin-master\samples\forecastweatherapi-simp
t find the path specified)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:318)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\apigee-deploy-maven-plugin-master%20(3)\apigee-depl
\target\apiproxy\targets\default.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at io.apigee.buildTools.enterprise4g.mavenplugin.ConfigureMojo.configurePackage(ConfigureMojo.java:74)
        at io.apigee.buildTools.enterprise4g.mavenplugin.ConfigureMojo.execute(ConfigureMojo.java:50)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
```

Comment: Do you have file: C:\apigee-deploy-maven-plugin-master%20(3)\apigee-depl
\target\apiproxy\targets\default.xml? If not, why is maven looking for it? Are you missing a config option? Do you reference this file directly in your config.json? Have you tried creating this file and seeing what happens next?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer is right, Maven could not find this \default.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion is to use a sane path for maven in windows. I would move out of (%20 directory) in "C:\apigee-deploy-maven-plugin-master%20(3)\"

Please do reply back if the issue still persists.

Comment: I forgot to update it , this was the issue and I just discovered it after I put in the question .

Answer (score 0):

Maven chokes on special characters in paths - generally this includes all of the reserved characters specified in [rfc1738](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt). With paths this typically boils down to a space in the path name which gets encoded but chokes subsequent calls to load files on that path.